Custom StringDeserializer in a Spring Web MVC Project
I'm working on a Spring MVC project and I need to globally override the default StringDeserializer provided by Jackson to sanitize incoming JSON strings. My goal is to apply this sanitization to all String fields in my DTOs without having to annotate each fiels individually (more that 200 DTOs to cover).
I have created a custom StringDeserializer and added it in a Spring Configuration, but it is never called.
The custom deserializer:
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.safety.Safelist;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer;

public class SanitizeDeserializer extends StringDeserializer {

  @Override
  public String deserialize(
      final JsonParser aParser,
      final DeserializationContext aContext) throws IOException {
    // this code is never executed
    return Jsoup.clean(super.deserialize(aParser, aContext), Safelist.none());
  }    
}

The Spring configuration to register the Deserializer:
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

@Configuration
public class SanitizeConfiguration {
    
  @Bean
  public Module addSanitizeStringDeserializer() {
    // this code is well executed when running the app
    final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(String.class, new SanitizeDeserializer());
    return module;
  }
}

REST controller sample:
 @PutMapping("/document/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> save(@RequestBody DocumentDTO document) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(document.getId());
    }

@Getters
@Setters
public class DocumentDTO {
  // I want these String fields to be sanitize before the setter is called when deserializing the JSON
  private String id;
  private String title;
  private String content;
}

I put a breakpoint in the deserialize method, but it is never called, it breaks in the Jackson StringDeserializer method.
Am I doing something wrong, or am I missing a configuration?
Or maybe it is not feasible to customize serializer on an already defined type?
Edit 1:
I tried configuring MessageConverters, but it override the default conf (WebMvcConfigurationSupport.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters), and while all String fields are well deserialized by custom deserializer, the XML content conversion is not working as before.
  @Override
  public void configureMessageConverters(
      final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> aConverters) {
    final Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder iBuilder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().deserializerByType(String.class,
        new SanitizeDeserializer());
    aConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(iBuilder.build()));
    // if i remove the following line, the XML response are not handle (500 error)
    // but with this line, XML reponse are XML escaped and become invalid
    aConverters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().xml().build()));
  }

Then I tried what suggested in comment, to add a Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder Bean, but it is still not used:
  @Bean
  public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder configureJackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {
    final Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder iBuilder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    final SimpleModule iSanitizeModule = new SimpleModule("sanitize-module");
    iSanitizeModule.addDeserializer(String.class, new SanitizeDeserializer());
    iBuilder.modules(iSanitizeModule);
    return iBuilder;
  }

  @Bean
  public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter configureMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter iConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    iConverter.setObjectMapper(configureJackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().build());
    return iConverter;
  }


You're reinventing the wheel here. Why not use hibernate-validator? Then you just put annotations like @Max, @Min, @Range, etc. on the fields.

If possible I prefer not to have to put an annotation for each String, for all hundreds of DTOs in my app. Hibernate validator can do this without annotating each field?

do you really have "hundreds" of dtos? How would you know what rule to apply to each field? You're going to do hundreds of name compares?

I don't want to do name compares, just to apply the same rule for all String fields when deserializing.

did u tried adding a breakpoint to addSanitizeStringDeserializer() method? does it get instantiaated?

also have you defined any other Jackson related beans yourself? Is this a SpringBoot project?

@asgarov1 yes i have a breakpoint and it gets instantiated. It's a Spring MVC project, there are no other Jackson beans configured.  I tried to replace the Module bean with an ObjectMapper bean that registers the module with the deserializer, in vain.

well, taking a step back, what kind of validation are you trying to do generically to all strings on the planet?

Without Spring Boot auto configuration, and specificaly jackson auto configuration wont automatically register modules. You have to explicitly import JacksonAutoConfiguration. Alternatively you could just define your own Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder bean and register your modules there

@SledgeHammer it is not an uncommon requirement in projects that want to implement some kind of sanitization on the DTOs they process. So it is not all Strings on the planet but all Strings that will be deserialized, which basically means all attributes that are of type String in any JSON they receive as a RequestBody. Registering custom Deserializer or alternatively BeanDeserializerModifier is the usual approach

Thanks @asgarov1, I tried to add a custom MessageConverter, but still not working as expected, so I removed if. I edited my post with new changes and tried your proposition to use a Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder bean.  Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder is correctly built, I also added a MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter bean, but my custom Deserializer is not called. Is there a missing configuration ?

I finally found the solution, by using extendMessageConverters instead of configureMessageConverters :)

Here is the working solution, that keeps default Spring MessageConverters, and add a customized deserializer in the Jackson JSON converter.
The code for the custom Deserializer
public class SanitizeDeserializer extends StringDeserializer {

  @Override
  public String deserialize(
      final JsonParser aParser,
      final DeserializationContext aContext) throws IOException {
    return Jsoup.clean(super.deserialize(aParser, aContext), Safelist.none());
  }    
}

And then, in @EnableWebMvc class extending WebMvcConfigurer, override the extendMessageConverters to replace the default Jackson JSON MessageConverter by your custom one:
@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(
    final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> aConverters) {
  aConverters.removeIf(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class::isInstance);
  final Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder iBuilder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().deserializerByType(String.class,
      new SanitizeDeserializer());
  aConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(iBuilder.build()));
}

See Spring documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-config/message-converters.html#page-title
